# performance issue in C++ codility challenge

Tags: c++, performance, algorithm

**EDIT: THE PROBLEM is actually algorithmic ( thanks to molbdnilo  below answer ) the failing case is O(N2) --> quadratic. People below are actually trying to find a true worst case O( N Log(N) ) time complexity algorithm.**

I took the codility challenge for this month. It took me about an hour to have 100% Correct O( N Log(N) ) time complexity algorithm.

But as you can see in the below I got 75% in performance, because one of the test took 10 times to long to run. And I do not get why! ***Could you point me to my mistakes ?***

1. https://codility.com/cert/view/
2. https://codility.com/cert/view/certD6ZTBR-RJTNQE24V242YRCV/details

Point 2 contains complete problem description and complete reports (test cases and timing) for my solution.

Roughly, I add each rope after another and update the path to root (ancestors) from the added node position, with the new maximum weight that can be added "under/below" each ancestors.

Here is the Code:

```
    // you can use includes, for example:
    #include <algorithm>
    #include <vector>
    #include <map>
    #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;
    // you can write to stdout for debugging purposes, e.g.
    // cout << "this is a debug message" << endl;


    struct node
    {
        int max_to_add;
        int id;
        node* mummy;
    };

    std::map< int, node* > nodes;

    bool insertRope( int durability, int pos, int Id, int weight )
    {
        node* n = new node;
        n->id = Id;
        nodes[Id] = n;

        if( pos == -1 )
        {
            n->max_to_add = durability - weight;
            n->mummy = NULL;
            if( n->max_to_add < 0 ) return false;
        }
        else
        {
            std::map< int, node* >::iterator it = nodes.find(pos);
            if( it != nodes.end() )
            {
                node* parent = (*it).second;

                n->mummy = parent;
                n->max_to_add = std::min( ( parent->max_to_add - weight),  (durability - weight) ) ;
                if( n->max_to_add < 0 ) return false;

                node* current = n;
                while ( (current = current->mummy) != NULL )
                {
                    current->max_to_add = current->max_to_add - weight;
                    if( current->max_to_add < 0 ) 
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        return true;
    }

    int solution(vector<int> &A, vector<int> &B, vector<int> &C) {
        // write your code in C++11

        for(int i = 0; i < A.size() ; ++i) 
        {
            if( insertRope( A[i], C[i],i,B[i] ) == false ) {return i;} 
        }

        return A.size();
    }

    int main()
    {

        /*static const int arrA[] = {4, 3, 1};
        vector<int> vecA (arrA, arrA + sizeof(arrA) / sizeof(arrA[0]) );

        static const int arrB[] = {2, 2, 1};
        vector<int> vecB (arrB, arrB + sizeof(arrB) / sizeof(arrB[0]) );


        static const int arrC[] = {-1, 0, 1};
        vector<int> vecC (arrC, arrC + sizeof(arrC) / sizeof(arrC[0]) );
        */


        static const int arrA[] = {5, 3, 6, 3, 3};
        vector<int> vecA (arrA, arrA + sizeof(arrA) / sizeof(arrA[0]) );

        static const int arrB[] = {2, 3, 1, 1, 2};
        vector<int> vecB (arrB, arrB + sizeof(arrB) / sizeof(arrB[0]) );


        static const int arrC[] = {-1, 0, -1, 0, 3};
        vector<int> vecC (arrC, arrC + sizeof(arrC) / sizeof(arrC[0]) );

        int sol = solution(vecA,vecB,vecC);

        system("PAUSE");
        return 0;
    }
```

**EDIT 1:**
Following Rafid suggestion I used new[], better, but I still have the perf issue:
https://codility.com/cert/view/certRT5YDP-W65HGPF28B5RN5AY/details

Comment: What platform are you on ? I'd suggest using callgrind to see where your bottleneck is. Also this fails (performance wise) on a quite large set of input data (100k) so try to use a representative input set of data yourself.

Comment: I'm on VS2010 on windows 7 64bits. I've no idea on what platform they test. callgrind is not available on windows? maybe with verysleepy...

Comment: callgrind isn't available on windows afaik. VerySleepy will give you information that could be usefull.

Comment: I'll test that at home unless i can go around missing admin rights and install it here. :)

Comment: I think you're timing out when building a long line (without branches) because in order to adjust `max_to_add`, you're traversing all the nodes every time you insert (quadratic time, IIRC).

Comment: Yes i just got that one 5min ago! Wrong complexity detection by codility ! Write it as an answer and I'll choose it!

Comment: Though in this case I have no idea of the o( n log n) algorithm !

Answer (score 1):

One performance tip that I can point out is: avoid using the 'new' operator repeatedly as it is expensive. You can create a large block of memory to start with and then use it whenever you need so that you don't allocate memory in the heap repeatedly.

Comment: yes that's a nice one. is there some "reserve" function on the map? like map.reserve( vec.size() ) ?

Comment: Well, there is no such method as far as I know, but that's not what I was referring to. I was referring to the first line in the insertRope() method.

Comment: Oh! I got it: in solution, I should preallocate node* to sizeof(Node) times A.size() an reuse these nodes ? Is that what you meant ?

Comment: you can see the new working solution with New[] here: https://codility.com/cert/view/certRT5YDP-W65HGPF28B5RN5AY/details

Same problem with perf !

Comment: `std::map<int, node> nodes;` should be sufficient.

Comment: @Jarod42 why ? You mean creating the nodes at insertion in the global map ?

Comment: @user2346536: yes, you don't need extra indirection. `map` insertion keep pointer validity of other element (contrary to `std::vector`).

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer : I'm not 100% certain that this is what is causing your problem.

Notice that the case where you are performing very bad is the following :
100K items in "line" configuration.

If you look at your while loop you'll find your algorithm doesn't provide O(NlogN) worst case complexity. Worst case is all the ropes are aligned and you have to traverse the whole tree everytime you add a Node to change the `max_to_add`

This doesn't change the fact that you could probably (as suggested in some comments) do with a std::map alone and no pointers, which might provide better performance because you don't need `new`allocation everytime you create a node, you create them on the stack. Maybe use a std::unordered_map even.

EDIT:

OK I've found a way to have better complexity. You don't need to update the load of all the ropes, you just need to maintain the correct value on the Node that are leaf on your tree. This value should be the minimum of `max_to_add` of the node on this branch.

I'll post some code when i can.

Comment: yes as discussed with @molbdnilo in the above comment, the algorithm is indeed quadratic in the worst case. Though it would be an improvement,  an unordered map would leave it quadratic. Also I do not have access to a C++11 compiler here and Ican't use boost in a codility challenge.

Comment: About your edit: "You don't need to update the load of all the ropes". Yes you do! because an extra rope is not necessarily added to a leaf! example: Assume currently max_to_add = 1 for a leaf,  then add a weight=1 on each side of this leaf...

Comment: Try submit the code: https://codility.com/programmers/challenges/
Take the sulfur challenge!

Answer (score 1):

What if we just skip adding the elements to the map and try to count the current capacity of the node in place? It's hard to check it right now, but here's the code, that shows the idea.

```
bool process_node(std::vector<int> &A, std::vector<int> &B, std::vector<int> &C, int index) {

    int next_parent = C[index];

    A[index] -= B[index];

    while(next_parent != -1) {

        A[next_parent] -= B[index];
        if (A[next_parent] < 0) {
            return false;
        }

        next_parent = C[next_parent];
    }

    return true;
}

int solution(std::vector<int> &A, std::vector<int> &B, std::vector<int> &C) {

    for (int i = 0; i < A.size(); ++i) {
        if (!process_node(A, B, C, i)) {
            return i;
        }
    }

    return A.size();
}
```

It looks like `O(NlogN)` time since we do the parent look-up in a tree N times. And probably we avoid some extra traversing.

Comment: Tested : https://codility.com/cert/view/certGPRFST-ACA7DE4S8KBKPSAS/details

not working on every case.

Comment: added a check  
`bool process_node(std::vector<int> &A, std::vector<int> &B,  std::vector<int> &C, int index) {  
int next_parent = C[index];  
A[index] -= B[index];  
if (A[index] < 0) {  
return false;  
}  
  
while(next_parent != -1) {  
A[next_parent] -= B[index];  
if (A[next_parent] < 0) {  
return false;  
}  
next_parent = C[next_parent];
}
return true;
}
int solution(std::vector<int> &A, std::vector<int> &B, std::vector<int> &C) {

for (int i = 0; i < A.size(); ++i) {
if (!process_node(A, B, C, i)) {
return i;
}
}

return A.size();
}`
But probably it will fail on time. Can you check?

Comment: You can submit the code here: codility.com/programmers/challenges Choose the sulfur challenge! I can do it if you want.

Comment: I submitted this on codility.com and it has the same problem in terms of performance as your first implementation. (case with 100k items in line timed-out). On the other hand it is quite smaller, and maybe easier to see the possible worst case.

Comment: I've tried complitely differen ways without any success... We'll see the solution when released!